# How to create JWT access token in Fosite OAuth2?

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am using Fosite Go library to implement Oauth 2.0. I am able to implement whole OAuth call flow as well.
But access token type i am getting in response is not in jwt format and i want response in jwt format.

**Actual access token format:**

```
ms6VdvAcrcvhUAGa68KFn_9xzIzIRZ9N3Tslo42qNpo.W6fMB4oztBG2G2kt-cc38-8nDbeLxTBAQEybyCX9QA0
```

**Expected access token jwt format**

```
sflk2324hUAGa68KFn_sdfknl@d$Tslo42qNpo.W6fMB4oztBG2G2kt-cc38-8ns1lk34kj3l2nlslds.1DFl3k$lksjdljfs
```

if you will see in expected access token jwt format, there are three sections in the token separated by dot(".").

I am not sure what configuration i can do in fosite to provide me jwt format token and also from where we can customize the attribute of the jwt token.

I am not able to find any example on google as well. So, Please help me with this. Thanks!